# async vuex fetch action state filled if using variable in template getting error undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, async-await, vue-component, vuex

i have one async action vuex, im using map getters and component created function to fetch and fill data, if im using this store data inline object in template view console show error undefined, if i try acces variable only without inline object im getting undefined error for inline object, i think this error about async function not blocking main process component fully loaded and after async function filled variable

actions, state

```
 // state
   export const state = {
    app: null
   }

   // getters
   export const getters = {
    app: state => state.app,
   }

   // mutations
   export const mutations = {
   [types.FETCH_APP_SUCCESS] (state, { app }) {
     state.app = app
   },

   [types.FETCH_APP_FAILURE] (state) {
    state.app = null
   },

   [types.UPDATE_APP] (state, { app }) {
     state.app = app
   }
   }
 async fetchApp ({ commit }) {
 try {
  const { data } = await axios.get('/api/app/1')
  commit(types.FETCH_APP_SUCCESS, { app: data })
 } catch (e) {
  commit(types.FETCH_APP_FAILURE)
 }
}
```

component

```
<template>
 <div>
   {{app.name}}
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  middleware: 'auth',

created () {
  // i try here async and await
 this.$store.dispatch('app/fetchApp')
},

computed: mapGetters({
 app: 'app/app'
}),

metaInfo () {
 return { title: this.$t('home') }
}
}
</script>
```

state is filled
[image]

variable can see in html
[image]

but console this error
[image]

Comment: i see that you have `app/app`  but the url is `api/app` i think that generates the error

Comment: app/app means under app.js and state app, i can filled state, i think problem not in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app/app` is initially `null`, and your template does not have a `null` check on `app.name`, which results in the error you saw. You can either [conditionally render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) `app.name` in the template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="app">
      {{app.name}}
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Or use the empty string as `app/app`'s initial state instead of `null` in your store.

Comment: ahh yes, i turned null state to empty string and error fixed thnx

Comment: @SerkanDayicik No problem :)

Comment: @ton19 which version best practice are you think ? empty string state or template conditional rendering ?

Comment: It probably depends how you use it. I would at least initialize the state to empty string to avoid a potential `null` reference. If the empty string causes side effects (such as a poor UX), I would conditionally render it as well.